# If $xf \in L^2(\Bbb R)$, is $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I tried using Holder's inequality with $|f| = |f| \frac{(1+|x|)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(1+|x|)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$, or variant but I can't seem to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Let $f(x) = \chi(x) / x$ where $\chi(x) = 0$ for $\lvert x \rvert > 2$ and $\chi(x) = 1$ for $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$.

Comment: @EricThoma Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Fair, but I think a natural followup is whether $(1 + \lvert x \rvert) f \in L^2$ implies $f \in L^1$.

Comment: @EricThoma Thank you. Is the latter question true? Also if you do post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: The answer is to the second question is YES. To see this, set $g = (1+|x|)f$. Then the  question is whether $g \in L^2$ implies $f \in L^1$. This follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:$$\int |f| = \int \frac{|g|}{1+|x|} \le \left( \int |g|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \int (1+|x|)^{-2} \right)^{1/2}$$ .